# How to get back to a previous commit stage

Tags: git, github, push, git-commit

I was working with some people on a project. I made some changes on my local machine and then committed the changes. There was an error that my branch was behind the master branch. So I pulled these changes and committed mine. But then I realized that I had a lot of errors (which came after I pulled the changes on Github and merged it with my project) in my project and I had pushed the changes to the master branch along with the errors.

All I want to know is that how can I get back to a stage marked by a previous commit (which a teammate of mine did).

Answer (score 0):

You should check your modification with `git diff` and `git diff --cached` before commiting.

If you have not pushed yet, you can use : `git revert HEAD`

I also recommend you to check this [article](https://ncona.com/2011/07/how-to-delete-a-commit-in-git-local-and-remote/) and this [Git manipulation image](https://github.com/Palisanka/code-notes/blob/master/git.png)